# Notation of the Taylor Polynomial with Lagrange Remainder

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have this Theorem in my book:

> Consider $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function of class $C^1$ and $\overline{x}, d \in \mathbb{R^n}$. If $f$ is twice differentiable in the segment $(\overline{x}, \overline{x}+d)$, then exist $t \in (0,1)$ such that
>
> $$
> f(\overline{x}+d) = f(\overline{x}) + \nabla f(\overline{x})^{T}d + \dfrac{1}{2}d{^T} \nabla^2f(\overline{x}+td)d. 
> $$

So, I couldn't understand the last term notation. I don't know because this is valid for some $t \in (0,1)$ and I don't understand the notation.
For example, I know that if I consider in $\mathbb{R^2}$ the pair $(x,y) = \overline{x} + d$ and $\overline{x} = (a,b)$, I have

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b) + \\ &+\dfrac{1}{2}[f_{xx}(a,b)(x-a)^2 + 2f_{xy}(a,b)(x-a)(y-b) + f_{yy}(y-b)^2].
\end{align}$$

And, the second term I can write

$$
f_x(a,b)(x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b) = \nabla f(a,b)^T
\begin{bmatrix} x-a \\y -b \end{bmatrix} = 
\nabla f(a,b)^T
\left( \begin{bmatrix} x \\y  \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} a \\b   \end{bmatrix} \right).
$$

So, If I get $x = \overline{x}+d$ I have

$$
f(\overline{x} + d) = f(\overline{x}) + \nabla f(\overline{x})^T(x-\overline{x}) = f(\overline{x}) + \nabla f(\overline{x})^Td. 
$$

Now I can't understand the last term notation.

Could someone please explain the last notation and about the choose with $t$ in the last term of theorem in human language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote doesn't make sense. I hope your book isn't writing the last term like that, or the author is using a strange notation.

What you should have is something like this $${1\over 2} d^T H_f(\overline{x}) d$$ where $H_f(\overline{x})$ is the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) which is the matrix of all the second order partial derivatives of a function. For a function $$f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$ the Hessian is of the form $$H_f(\overline{x}) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}&\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}& \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\end{bmatrix}$$ Most of the times, for [Schwartz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) the off diagonal element are the same. Now you can see how this term make's sense.

The notation used by the book is, most of the times, the [Laplace's operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) which is a totally different thing.

Comment: The book that I am reading is about Optimization and the notation $\nabla^2 f(\overline{x})$ is the $H_f(\overline{x})$.
But I couldn't understand this notation.

Comment: But, I think that I can understand this term. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give me some good Calculus book that deals with this in detail please?

Comment: I really like Lang's books, there're several of them on multivariable or vector calculus. But a quick search on google will give you many other results!

Comment: Just as an aside, here on MSE you should give points and accept an answer to your post if you think you got what you were searching. This let's other MSE users know that the forum is closed and gives to the user that answered points

Comment: Davide Morgante, I didn't know this site. My friend told me and I started here with this question. Sorry, but I don't know how I give points for your answer. You help me and of course I will search about this notation on google and Lang's books.

Comment: Don't worry! The points are given any time you accept an answer and any time somebody upvotes the answer.